# Font size shrinks when I add Boostrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, font-size, css-specificity

The font size changes when I add the Boostrap CDN link.

I found that this is because Boostrap has a default font size. I tried to change the font size by specifying the font size in the external style sheet and putting `!import`, but it doesn't work. And it only works when I put font size in the inline style sheet.

```css
div.banner {
    font-size: 500% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <div class="banner">
    <h1 class="slideUp" style="font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif">
      Yasuní National Park<br />
      <span style="font-size: 40%">&nbsp; between oil exploitation and conservation</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

This is the part of my code and I was trying to change the font size of `<h1>` tag by applying the code below. But it doesn't work. Can you explain why?

```css
div.banner {
    font-size: 500% !important;
}
```

Comment: `div.banner` should be `div.banner h1` because Bootstrap overrides the `<h1>` font size.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we change the size of font sizes using em, rem, and px.

Given CSS:

Let us say you have you font size declared for your entire document like this

```
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

that is in pixel.

If we want to change this part of your code.

```
<span style="font-size: 40%;">&nbsp; between oil exploitation and conservation</span></h1>
```

We use rem mostly. like:

```
<span style="font-size: 2rem;">&nbsp; between oil exploitation and conservation</span></h1>



//2rem means -> default 20px(declared) * 2 = 40px will be the font-size of 2rem, 3 rem is 60, etc.
```

I see you tagged `specificity` too..

Not a good practice to use `important` even in testing.

Highest priority is `inline styling -> then IDs -> classes.`

Comment: Thank you for the information! Is there any reason % is not used?

Comment: Percentage works fine, not a good practice though. 100% is equal to current declared font-size. And 150% is equal to 1.5em. Or your 40% is equal to .4em. Using percentage will confuse you to which it refers rather than em is relative to parent and rem is relative to html element.